# M2.3.3: Sending different order confirmation email if payment method is bank transfer

Tags: magento2.3.3, payment-banktransfer, order-confirmation-email

How to send a different kind of order confirmation email (maybe using different email template or just add some extra text to the one template) if customer has used bank transfer payment method?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a preference for the "prepareTemplate" function available in the below  file

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php

You can put your respective business logic in this function to set different email templates for different payment methods.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm sorry but I need more detailed answer.